# Temporary files on Travis

Tags: node.js, gruntjs, travis-ci

I have a Javascript project which uses Grunt for build process, QUnit for tests, Blanket for code coverage and a custom Grunt task to convert coverage results into LCOV files, sended to Coveralls. Everything running on TravisCI.

the project : https://github.com/mistic100/jQuery-QueryBuilder
my Grunt task : https://github.com/mistic100/grunt-qunit-blanket-lcov

So what should happen is that `npm test` runs QUnit+Blanket tests in a PhantomJS process and in the meanwhile, coverage results are saved in `.coverage-results/all.lcov`.

After a successfull build, `grunt coveralls` sends this file to Coveralls.

And my problem is here, the task does not find the file, although when I test on my computer it does.

see the last Travis log: https://travis-ci.org/mistic100/jQuery-QueryBuilder#L389

The only thing I can think about is that the file, for some reason, is deleted once `npm test` is finished. Is it possible ?

---

**edit**
so this has nothing to do with Travis but with my Grunt task where I use absolute paths thinking it's relative paths (I still don't know why it doesn't append on Windows though)

Answer (score 0):

> The only thing I can think about is that the file, for some reason, is deleted once npm test is finished. Is it possible ?

No, lifecycle-wise the build artefacts are still present, when running `after_success` commands.

The gruntfile.js configures force true and defines path - no issue here. 
This should work.

I would suggest to throw in some commands to check the folders and files on Travis.

- `- sudo ls -alh /home/travis/build/mistic100/jQuery-QueryBuilder/*`
- `- sudo ls -alh /home/travis/build/mistic100/jQuery-QueryBuilder/.coverage-results/*`

Maybe you spot a permission issue during folder and file creation.
But that's my only guess.

Comment: https://travis-ci.org/mistic100/jQuery-QueryBuilder#L389 the folder is here but not the file. Perhaps `fs.appendFileSync` can't create the file, I'll try to touch it beforehand.

Comment: So the problem is really `fs.appendFileSync` which can't access the file, I added a `grunt.file.write` with empty content, and the file stay empty.